# SQL Server error: result of 'text()' expression is statically 'empty'

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

If anybody can help it would be great because I've spent a few hours and don't know how to fix it...

I have in one existing code (as I understand it tries read XML from dbo table field):

```
with usluga_list as (
    --EvnUslugaList
)
select top 1
    cast(doc.EvnXml_Data.query('data/@XmlDataSection_SysNick/text()') as nvarchar(max)) as value
from 
    usluga_list u
    cross apply (
        select top 1 *
            from v_EvnXml with(nolock)
        where u.EvnUsluga_id = Evn_id
            order by EvnXml_insDT desc
    ) doc
order by
    EvnXml_insDT --SqlOrderType_SysNick
```

When this code runs, I get this error:

> Error number: 42000/2377 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]XQuery [doc.EvnXml_Data.query()]: Result of 'text()' expression is statically 'empty'

The error gives it snippet:

```
doc.EvnXml_Data.query('data/@XmlDataSection_SysNick/text()')
```

but how to prevent it or check for null and output another value, I don't know.

Need a SQL Server guru!

Comment: What is `@XmlDataSection_SysNick`? An attribute in the XML? A TSQL variable?

Comment: @XmlDataSection_SysNick it's a variable.

Comment: the answer you accepted expects there to be an attribute called `XmlDataSection_SysNick` 

Comment: Sorry, Martin, what u mean?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3b2cf89eb43e5c0fb706e536381aba3

Comment: Martin, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3a1fd9932f7d437fc407ae36bfaf4d0, second variant. As I see in code (PHP) I have $rquest['XmlDataSection_SysNick'] = 'result' and in side db exist XML <data>...<result></result>...</data>. So then we have something like (data/result)[1].  I've checked, accepted answer return result if <result> exist in the XML and not fire error if it absent. What is wrong here?

Comment: Well that is different code from what you have in your question and doesn't contain `@` at all

Comment: Do u think I need to change the question text and change @... to result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
cast(doc.EvnXml_Data.query('data/@XmlDataSection_SysNick/text()') as nvarchar(max)) as value
```

By this:

```
doc.EvnXml_Data.value('(data/@XmlDataSection_SysNick)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as value
```